# JavaScript - Search for first character in an Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, math, search, random

I'm trying to find the first character in an Array in JavaScript.

I have this a random function (not the best, but I am going to improve it):

```
function random() {
var Rand = Math.floor(Math.random()*myArray.length);
document.getElementById('tr').innerHTML = myArray[Rand];
}
```

And here's my Array list.

```
myArray = ["where", "to", "get", "under", "over", "why"];
```

If the user only wants arrays with W's, only words with a W in the first letter is shown. (Like "where" or "why")

I do not have a lot of experience with JavaScript from before and I have been sitting with this problem for ages.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's `indexOf()` method of an array/string which can provide you with a position of a letter. **First letter** has a position of **0(zero)**, so

```
function filter(letter) {
  var results = [];
  var len = myArray.length;
  for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    if (myArray[i].indexOf(letter) == 0) results.push(myArray[i]);
  }
  return results;
}
```

Here is a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kR4EA/) for it. Before running open the console(Chrome: ctrl+shift+i, or console in FireBug) to see resulting arrays.

Comment: Could `myArray[i][0] == letter` be probably faster?

Comment: You should run a benchmark, howver it should be faster because there is no function call. Good point! :)

Comment: Thank you! Now I just added a `<textarea>` and returned the value of it.

Comment: @mistapink, direct index lookup on strings isn't specified in the ECMA standard. It just happens to work on some implementations. The standard way is `charAt`. `myArray[i].charAt(0) == letter`.

Comment: It dose not seem to work with my textarea. It returns nothing.

Comment: Post your code on jsFiddle. By the way, my code on jsFiddle didn't have "return results"; instead if has "console.dir(results);" so act accordingly :)

Comment: Sorry. It's just that I'm not very good at programming as I said. I'm looking for a way to implant this code with my random function and add like a text area in the HTML.

I tried this code
`if (myArray[i].charAt(0) == document.getElementById('spchar').value) results.push(nameList[i]);`

Answer (score 5):

You can filter the array to contain only specific values, such as the ones starting with 'w'

```
var words = ["where", "to", "get", "under", "over", "why"];
var wordsWithW = words.filter(function(word) {
  return word[0] == 'w';
});
var randomWordWithW = wordsWithW[Math.floor(Math.random() * wordsWithW.length];
... // operate on the filtered array afterwards
```

If you plan to support the *aged* browsers you might want to consider using [underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org/#filter) or [Prototype](http://api.prototypejs.org/language/Enumerable/prototype/findAll/)

When using underscore you could simply write this:

```
var randomWordWithW = _.chain(words).filter(function(word) {
  return word[0] == 'w';
}).shuffle().first().value()
```

Comment: This looks kinda hard to implent to the random function. Do you know how?

Comment: @user1426486 updated my answer so you can see how to pick a random element from it.

Comment: My whole JavaScript code dose not even work when implenting the code. I am not so experienced, so I can't see the problem with it.